# How to display input from HTML on servlet?

Tags: servlets, httprequest

I'm trying to learn some of the basics of web programming.  As such, I want to make a make an HTML page with a text box that says submit.  When submit is pressed, I want the data in the text box to be sent to a servlet.  When I go to the servlet URL (in browser) I want to have all the messages displayed in chronological order.  I've done the html part as follows.

```
    <form action="./DisplayMessage" method = post">
        <div>


        Message:<br>
            <input type="text" name="New_Message"><br>
            <input type="submit" />

        </div>
    </form>
```

Where "DisplayMessage" is the name of my servlet.  This part is good enough for my learning purpose.  My servlet is the issue.  Currently, it only shows the most recent message sent, I want all of the messages.  Here's a snippet of what I have so far.

```
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    Enumeration parameter = request.getParameterNames();
    while(parameter.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String paramName = (String) parameter.nextElement();
        out.println("<br>" + request.getParameter(paramName));

    }
```

I realize it's got more than it needs, but I want to expand on it later.

Any help is great, thank you for your time.

Comment: You only have one textbox for messages, and you want all of the messages to be displayed?

Comment: @Yamakenji Yeah, sorry if that's confusing. I just want that for input then when going to the servlet URL I want to see all the messages posted.

Comment: If you post a message to the servlet it is available as a request parameter. The servlet will send a response and you can include the message that was sent in the request. If you send a new request, the servlet does not remember the previous request. It can only see what you just sent it. If you want to persist old messages you can either put them in the session (like an in memory store) or you can write them out to a database (or a file).

Comment: Storing them in session sounds exactly like what I want.  Do you have any resources on how to learn to do that, or perhaps a suggestion?